# Please assist me to Solve this issue (New Installation + Hello world Project) build failed / Generate APKs Failed

Tags: android-studio, build.gradle

Executing tasks: [clean, :app:assembleDebug]

> Configure project :
>   This version of Gradle requires version 2.0.2 of the build scan plugin or later.
>   Please see https://gradle.com/scans/help/gradle-incompatible-plugin-version for more information.
>
> Task :clean UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:clean
>   Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:preDebugBuild
>   Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
>   Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
>   Task :app:checkDebugManifest
>   Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig
>   Task :app:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:generateDebugSources
>   Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug
>   Task :app:mainApkListPersistenceDebug
>   Task :app:generateDebugResValues
>   Task :app:generateDebugResources
>   Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

  > 8 exceptions were raised by workers:
  >   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.0-5326820-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
  >   This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.0-5326820-windows Daemon #1: Daemon startup failed
  >   This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.0-5326820-windows Daemon #2: Daemon startup failed
  >   This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.0-5326820-windows Daemon #3: Daemon startup failed
  >   This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.0-5326820-windows Daemon #4: Daemon startup failed
  >   This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.0-5326820-windows Daemon #5: Daemon startup failed
  >   This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.0-5326820-windows Daemon #6: Daemon startup failed
  >   This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.0-5326820-windows Daemon #7: Daemon startup failed
  >   This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
10 actionable tasks: 8 executed, 2 up-to-date

Answer (score 0):

Issue was that I followed tutorial created for non-mobile devices.
Which meant Unitys build options requires special option for mobile builds.

```
newBuildPlayerOptions.options = BuildOptions.AcceptExternalModificationsToPlayer;
```